# Execute Python from PHP error

Tags: php, python

I am trying to execute a python script in PHP. The PHP code runs fine, but when I uncomment line A or line B in the python script to use a library, the PHP code stops working.

I simplified my code to a minimum to find the error, without success. What can I try?

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $abc = passthru("python test.py");
    echo $abc;
?>
```

Python code:

```
#from lxml import html #Line A
#import lxml.html  # Line B

def getChat(rfc , password):
    print rfc
    print password

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getChat('rfc', 'password')
```

Output: `rfc password`.

error.log:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "../cfdipython/test.py", line 5, in  import lxml.html File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/**init**.py", line 42, in  from lxml import etree ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _xmlBufContent Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libxml2.2.dylib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so

Comment: Did you try running the python script directly from the terminal to see what error(s) you get?

Comment: Yes. if i run the script directly from the terminal, i dont get errors, all works fine, I use the lxml library in other .py code, and works fine, the problem is when I try to execute a .py from PHP using lxml library...

Comment: Check your server log(s). In Apache on Linux, the relevant one is at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I'm stumped, but you should edit your question to include that. Also, Google `import lxml error`, there's a bunch of stuff on it.

Comment: Possibly have something to do with your `PATH`.

Comment: but, when i execute .py from console, all works fine, why dont in php?